# Understanding covariance and lowerbound in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, type-bounds

I struggle to understand Scala's covariance in combination with lower bounds. I will illustrate my confusion in the following code snippet with **2 compilation errors**.

```scala
class Queue[+T]:
  def enqueue[U >: T](x: U): Queue[U] = null

class IntQueue extends Queue[Int]:
  override def enqueue[Int](x: Int): Queue[Int] =
    println(math.sqrt(x)) // 1) Found: (x : Int) Required: Double
    super.enqueue(x)      // 2) Found: Queue[Any] Required: Queue[Int]
```

First, there is a generic class `Queue` which takes one type parameter with covariance annotation `+`. This is OK as I want to make assignments such as `val a: Queue[Any] = IntQueue()`. Its `enqueue` method has a lower bound for its type parameter, `U >: T`. This is needed because the `x` would otherwise be in a contravariant position, allowing for nasty things, similar to `ArrayStoreException` in Java's `Array`.
Second, there is a parametrized class `IntQueue` generated by `Queue` with specific type being `Int`.

**Questions** – why the 1) and 2) compiler errors happen

ad 1)

- My reasoning is that `math.sqrt` is defined as `def sqrt(x: Double): Double`. My argument's type, `x`, is of type `Int`. In this case, implicit conversion `Int->Long->Float->Double` should happen. Why does the compiler doesn't perform implicit conversion?

Comment: Since an `IntQueue` could be lifted as a `Queue[Any]` then you must be able to receive anything, not only `Int`, on `enqueue` and probably return something different than `IntQueue`

Comment: Switch on `-Xlint:type-parameter-shadow` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443888/what-causes-this-type-error-in-a-pattern-guard-for-matching-list-of-tuples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718070/type-parameters-applied-to-scala-function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725562/type-arguments-and-bounds-in-scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779586/returning-functions-that-check-for-equality-ordinal-comparison-for-any-valid-typ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751823/two-type-parameters-with-the-same-name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090756/scala-really-weird-type-mismatch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178377/java-generics-the-type-parameter-string-is-hiding-the-type-string

Comment: Correct overriding for `T=Int` would be https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/h1aJbMcATGmIF4XrfD3bTg/2 Now the error is `Found: (x : U); Required: Double`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598220/strange-error-with-string-in-scala-2-12-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your overriding method definition, `Int` is not what you expect. You're actually defining a type parameter called `Int` but not referring to the "original" `Int` type and thus "hiding" the original `Int` type.

You actually wrote the same as:

```scala
override def enqueue[I](x: I): Queue[I] = ...
```

Declare it as a non overriding method to achieve what you expect:

```
def enqueue(x: Int): Queue[Int] = ...
```

Comment: so If I understand it correctly, you implicitly specify what type parameter `U` is inside `IntQueue.enqueue` by declaring what its argument type is – `x: Int`

Comment: You only implicitly define that `U >: Int` but you cannot define anything stronger, that would violate the contract of `Queue` which is that you can enqueue any other element with is a super type of `Int`. That's why you cannot define this method with `override`. It must be another method.

Comment: you can define method with `override`: `override def enqueue[U >: Int](x: U): Queue[U]` compiles just fine

Comment: @Talos, yes you can but that's not what you expected in the 1st place: the method can be called with anything which is a supertype of `Int` and you will return a `QUeue[U]`, not a `IntQUeue`.